# Pattern matching inside closed type families

Tags: haskell, type-families

I'm incompetently trying to play with the new closed type family feature of GHC 7.8
and I would like to find a nice way to branch on type level constructs.

I have something like

```
data (:::) :: Symbol -> * -> * where

data Result = Pre | Post | Match

type family Cmp a b :: Result where
    Cmp (s ::: t) (s ::: t) = Match
    Cmp (s1 ::: t1) (s2 ::: t2) = ???
```

where I would like to return different types depending on the result of
`CmpSymbol` in GHC.TypeLits. It feels like something like

```
Cmp (s1 ::: t1) (s2 ::: t2) = (CmpSymbol s1 s2 ~ LT) => Pre
Cmp (s1 ::: t1) (s2 ::: t2) = (CmpSymbol s1 s2 ~ GT) => Post
```

should work, but it does not. Interestingly it's not a syntax error but
instead a complaint that it is ill kinded.

I can somehow get it to work by using undecidable instances and a
helper function:

```
type family Cmp a b :: Result where
    Cmp (s ::: t) (s ::: t) = Match
    Cmp (s1 ::: t1) (s2 ::: t2) = Fun (CmpSymbol s1 s2)

type family Fun r :: Result where
    Fun LT = Pre
    Fun GT = Post
```

But this feels rather clunky, surely there is a nicer way? Also ghci says
something like `:kind! Cmp ("a" ::: Int) ("a" ::: String)` has type `Fun 'EQ`
even though `Fun` is closed. Why is that? I also can't see an easy way to
work with ordinary classes here? What if the definition of `Fun` was something
like

```
class Fun2 o r
instance Fun2 LT Pre
instance Fun2 GT Post
```

Is there any way to talk to type classes in a nice way or am I restricted to just
using other type families like `Fun`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really is the only way, although I like to define some reusable type functions (`==` and `If`), in your case it would become `If (CmpSymbol s1 s2 == LT) Pre Post`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to get a type function of kind `LT -> Pre` from a class like `Fun2.`

Your example has kind `Fun EQ` because `CmpSymbol "a" "a"` is `EQ` and you pass this to `Fun`. The reason it doesn't just give an error is type families are evaluated as late as possible - here you don't ask for the "value" of `Fun EQ` so it isn't necessary to evaluate it yet.